# Call fancybox with jquery element

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, fancybox

I know there is a way to call fancybox manually with a string of html like so:

```
$.fancybox("<div>foo</div>")
```

However, i want to instead pass a jQuery object to the fancybox so i can retain things like .data() and click() events i have already added:

```
var $fooObj = $("div.foo").data("foo","bar");
$.fancybox($fooObj);
```

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You just need to set it as the `content` property in the options you pass into `$.fancybox()`, like this:

```
$.fancybox({
    content: $fooObj 
});
```

[You can test it out here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/WNacK/).

Comment: Brilliant! Can't believe they don't make this more obvious in their description of the "content" property.  Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2):

```
function LaunchFancyBox(code)
{
    jQuery.fancybox({
        content: code 
    });     
}
```

And in the onclick/click:

```
<a href="#" onclick="LaunchFancyBox('<div>test</div>'); return false;">Launch it baby</a>!
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Way!!!

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.fancybox({
        'width': '80%',
        'height': '80%',
        'autoScale': true,
        'transitionIn': 'fade',
        'transitionOut': 'fade',
        'type': 'iframe',
        'href': 'http://www.example.com'
    });
});
```